# HTML/CSS radio button multi-level accordion closes automatically on selection

Tags: html, css

I've grabbed a few examples from multiple codepen sources to create a multi-level accordion just with HTML/CSS using the type radio button. When you click on the 'main' radio button it opens up and if you click on the other 'main' radio button it closes the previous radio button however if you open the 'main' radio button then click on the radio button inside the radio button it does not open it closes the 'main' radio button, see example [here](https://codepen.io/tom-han/pen/YzXErBW).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Settings</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="accordion">
            <div class="accordion-tab">
                <input type="radio" id="radio-1" class="accordion-input" name="accordion">
                <label class="accordion-label" for="radio-1"></label>
                <div class="accordion-content">
                    <div class="accordion-info">
                        <div class="platform-image"></div>
                        <span class="platform-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="total-games">
                        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="accordion-tab-content">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="accordion-tab">
                            <input type="radio" id="radio-2" class="accordion-input" name="accordion">
                            <label class="accordion-label" for="radio-2"></label>
                            <div class="accordion-content">
                                <div class="accordion-info">
                                    <div class="game-image"></div>
                                    <span class="game-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="total-games">
                                    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="accordion-tab-content">
                                <div class="wrapper">
                                    <div>
                                        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin id congue dolor. Vivamus eleifend vitae nunc sed tincidunt.</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="accordion-tab">
                <input type="radio" id="radio-3" class="accordion-input" name="accordion">
                <label class="accordion-label" for="radio-3"></label>
                <div class="accordion-content">
                    <div class="accordion-info">
                        <div class="platform-image"></div>
                        <span class="platform-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="total-games">
                        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="accordion-tab-content">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="accordion-tab">
                            <input type="radio" id="radio-4" class="accordion-input" name="accordion">
                            <label class="accordion-label" for="radio-4"></label>
                            <div class="accordion-content">
                                <div class="accordion-info">
                                    <div class="game-image"></div>
                                    <span class="game-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="total-games">
                                    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="accordion-tab-content">
                                <div class="wrapper">
                                    <div>
                                        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin id congue dolor. Vivamus eleifend vitae nunc sed tincidunt.</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    background-color: #6fcae7;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#accordion {
    margin: 50px 0 0;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.accordion-tab {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px; /* 10px adds to bottom */
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ececec;
}
.accordion-tab:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}

.accordion-input {
    display: none;
}

.accordion-input:checked ~ .accordion-content + .accordion-tab-content {
    max-height: 3000px;
}

.accordion-input:checked ~ .accordion-content:after {
    transform: rotate(0);
}

.accordion-label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-content {
    position: relative;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 0 87px 0 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.accordion-content:before, .accordion-content:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.accordion-content:before {
    height: 100%;
}

.accordion-label:hover ~ .accordion-content:after {
  background-image: url("accordion-arrow-hover.svg");
}

.accordion-content:after {
    width: 24px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("accordion-arrow.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.accordion-content + .accordion-tab-content {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height .3s;
}

.accordion-content > div, .total-games > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.accordion-info {
    width: 95%;
}

.accordion-tab-content {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    color: #363636;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 30px;
}

.platform-image {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.platform-name {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #242a32;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #242a32;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.total-games {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #5d5d5d;
}

.game-image {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.game-name {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #242a32;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #242a32;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use checkboxes because when one is checked, the other will uncheck.
With radio's, you can do it by the use of the name attribute. If the radio should have a toggle relationship, they should have the same name like in the example here below:

```css
body {
    background-color: #6fcae7;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#accordion {
    margin: 50px 0 0;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.accordion-tab {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px; /* 10px adds to bottom */
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ececec;
}
.accordion-tab:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}

.accordion-input {
    display: none;
}

.accordion-input:checked ~ .accordion-content + .accordion-tab-content {
    max-height: 3000px;
}

.accordion-input:checked ~ .accordion-content:after {
    transform: rotate(0);
}

.accordion-label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-content {
    position: relative;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 0 87px 0 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.accordion-content:before, .accordion-content:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.accordion-content:before {
    height: 100%;
}

.accordion-label:hover ~ .accordion-content:after {
  background-image: url("accordion-arrow-hover.svg");
}

.accordion-content:after {
    width: 24px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("accordion-arrow.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.accordion-content + .accordion-tab-content {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height .3s;
}

.accordion-content > div, .total-games > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.accordion-info {
    width: 95%;
}

.accordion-tab-content {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    color: #363636;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 30px;
}

.platform-image {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.platform-name {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #242a32;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #242a32;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.total-games {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #5d5d5d;
}

.game-image {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.game-name {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #242a32;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #242a32;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Settings</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="accordion">
            <div class="accordion-tab">
                <input type="radio" id="radio-1" class="accordion-input" name="accordion">
                <label class="accordion-label" for="radio-1"></label>
                <div class="accordion-content">
                    <div class="accordion-info">
                        <div class="platform-image"></div>
                        <span class="platform-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="total-games">
                        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="accordion-tab-content">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="accordion-tab">
                            <input type="radio" id="radio-2" class="accordion-input" name="sub-accordion-1">
                            <label class="accordion-label" for="radio-2"></label>
                            <div class="accordion-content">
                                <div class="accordion-info">
                                    <div class="game-image"></div>
                                    <span class="game-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="total-games">
                                    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="accordion-tab-content">
                                <div class="wrapper">
                                    <div>
                                        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin id congue dolor. Vivamus eleifend vitae nunc sed tincidunt.</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="accordion-tab">
                <input type="radio" id="radio-3" class="accordion-input" name="accordion">
                <label class="accordion-label" for="radio-3"></label>
                <div class="accordion-content">
                    <div class="accordion-info">
                        <div class="platform-image"></div>
                        <span class="platform-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="total-games">
                        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="accordion-tab-content">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="accordion-tab">
                            <input type="radio" id="radio-4" class="accordion-input" name="sub-accordion-2">
                            <label class="accordion-label" for="radio-4"></label>
                            <div class="accordion-content">
                                <div class="accordion-info">
                                    <div class="game-image"></div>
                                    <span class="game-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="total-games">
                                    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="accordion-tab-content">
                                <div class="wrapper">
                                    <div>
                                        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin id congue dolor. Vivamus eleifend vitae nunc sed tincidunt.</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      <div class="accordion-tab">
                            <input type="radio" id="radio-5" class="accordion-input" name="sub-accordion-2">
                            <label class="accordion-label" for="radio-5"></label>
                            <div class="accordion-content">
                                <div class="accordion-info">
                                    <div class="game-image"></div>
                                    <span class="game-name">Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="total-games">
                                    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="accordion-tab-content">
                                <div class="wrapper">
                                    <div>
                                        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin id congue dolor. Vivamus eleifend vitae nunc sed tincidunt.</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is it possible with checkbox to close the previous checkbox automatically like the radio button does automatically?

Comment: :) now that's possible with radio's and their names. Sorry I thought you where looking for a different solution at first. So I've updated my comment here above. Please see if this is what you like.

Comment: been mucking around for ages and after scanning you code it was setting different name="sub-accordion-2" for each radio type :) ty.

Comment: just wondering because a radio button is already checked that means you can't click on the same radio to close it right? no workaround other than javascript?

Comment: I think javascript will be a better choice indeed.